# How to give a user access just to one folder on Windows server 2008?

Tags: ftp, windows-server-2008

I have a development Windows server 2008. And I need to give one of my users access to folder on the server. User needs to have only access to this folder. He should be able to upload or delete files only within this folder using FTP.

shouldn't be able to get access using remote desktop connection.

How to configure it on windows server 2008?

Comment: Odd, this came here and not to serverfault...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with IIS, but it should be easy to setup it's FTP site and have it publish specified folder. Then open the FTP in the firewall. Should be good to go from there.  Remote Desktop Connection isn't an issue because only Power Users, Remote Desktop Users and Admins are allowed to RDP into Server 2008 without explicit permissions.